Pinging a role with discord js v14
I am trying to ping a role with discord.js; not just displaying the role name but sending a notification to all members with the role.
I have tried
await interaction.reply({
  embeds: [embed],
  components: [row],
  content: `<@&${team.id}>`,
  allowed_mentions: {
    roles: [`${team.id}`]
  }
});

I don't know if I have to place "allowed_mentions" in a different place or just to not use it. Perhaps I did not use it correctly.
I have also tried looking on my Discord settings. I placed my role on pingable by everyone, allowing the bot to ping everyone and the role assigned to the bot to ping everyone, but nothing changed.

You cannot mention other users or roles when responding to an interaction and I don’t believe there are any ways to override this behaviour. You must first defer the interaction for Discord, and then send the message content with the mentions as a message in the channel.
await interaction.deferUpdate();
await interaction.channel.send({
  content: `<@&${team.id}>`,
  embeds: [embed],
  components: [row],
});



Oh I didn't know this rule thanks. It seems like discord doesn't like the deferUpdate() in my case but the ping works now

Ok the deferUpdate() does not work on slash commands, you must reply to the interaction. An ephemeral message is the best way to end interaction I guess
